# How to make OpenJFX available directly?

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I installed OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11, and managed to build and run a JavaFX application. However, I was only able to run it after adding `--module-path` and `--add-modules` arguments in the command line.

How can I set up OpenJFX so that it is available by default to any application (without extra arguments), like with Oracle's JDK version 8?

Comment: @murkle thanks, I had actually found ZuluFX, but they didn't have version 11 available for Linux when I posted this question. In the meantime I contacted them and they added it. I am guessing they are doing something similar to the solution I found.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a way to do it. It's probably not advisable and may break things, but here it is anyway (note that I'm using Linux):

1. Get and extract the OpenJFX SDK and jmods. Following steps are relative to the root directory of the OpenJDK
2. Copy `*.so` from the OpenJFX's lib directory to `lib` (OpenJDK's lib directory)
3. Copy all the javafx jmod files to `jmods`
4. Run `` bin/jlink --module-path jmods --add-modules `ls -1 jmods|sed s/\\.jmod//|paste -sd ,` --output jfx `` (the command between backticks makes a comma-separated list of all the jmods without the .jmod extensions)
5. Move `jfx/lib/modules` to `lib/modules` (you can rename the original one first as a backup)
6. Delete the `jfx` directory

Comment: That is horrible.  Folks: don't do this kind of thing!

Comment: @StephenC what happened with your answer? I don't see it anymore.

Comment: Strange, I thought it was a decent response, even if I didn't really agree with it. Well, at least my answer is being showered with praise and enthusiasm :) (/sarcasm)

Comment: Not sarcasm.  I really don't think people should do this kind of thing.  But if it works for you ...

Comment: I meant I was being sarcastic about the reaction it received.